# How to create table name acording to input value?

Tags: java, sql, ddl, create-table

i want to make table according how user select value.if user select some value ...this value is used as table name in servlet.
I tried this ...is it valid?

```
String tbl = Branch + Year + Month; 

st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE" + tbl + "(Month varchar(10),purva varchar(10),yash varchar(10)");
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain more about how your application works, and why you are allowing users to create tables.  This is a very unusual requirement, and most likely you should only be allowing users to add information to tables which already exist.

Comment: Like @TimBiegeleisen said, this is probably not a good idea. But, the statement is missing a couple of spaces try this :  `st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + tbl + " (Month varchar(10),purva varchar(10),yash varchar(10)");`

Comment: Specify the schema name and wrap the table name in square brackets, eg st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE dbo.[" + tbl + "] (Month varchar(10),purva varchar(10),yash varchar(10)");

Comment: *.is it valid?*: your test should tell you that. Have you tested your code?

Comment: Multiple, identical, tables is usually a mistake.  Can't you put all the data into a single table?

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the potential of SQL injection attacks, you're missing spaces around the name of the table:

```
st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + tbl + " (Month varchar(10), purva varchar(10), yash varchar(10)");
// Here ----------------------^-----------^
```